# My android app crashes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer, handler

I have built a simple App which runs a service. In the app the user enters an address, and the service needs to calculate the distance between user location and the address that he entered. If the distance between them is smaller than 100 meters then  a toast message pops up. 
When I first run the app it's providing the distance correctly but after a couple of times that I run my app in different places the calculation of the distance is growing.
For example: I turn eclipse(at my home) then run the app on my device. I enter the address of my home and after calculating the distance, the distance is 5 meters so the toast message pops up. Then I go somewhere and enter a address of the place I'm going to and when I get there the toast mess pops up.
But when I return to my place and  run the app again (with a address of my home) withe the phone connected to eclipse, the distance is now 20 meters instead of 5 meters.
What can be the problem? And the app crushes some times....

MainActivity:

```
public void startMethod(View v)
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("from_position", latLngC);
    args.putParcelable("to_position", latLngD);


    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
    i.putExtra("bundle", args);
    startService(i);
}
```

MainService:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // 
    Bundle bundle = intent.getParcelableExtra("bundle");

    latLngC = bundle.getParcelable("from_position");//Getting the latlng of user position
    latLngD = bundle.getParcelable("to_position");//Getting the latlng of destination position

    timer = new Timer();
    //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            timerTask = new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            latLngC=setMyLocation(); // Getting users current location
                            double r = CalculationByDistance(latLngC, latLngD);
                             if(r<0.1){
                                  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                                final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                                //show the toast
                                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;  
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, duration);
                                toast.show();
                                        timer.cancel(); // stopping the timer 
                                        stopSelf();  // stopping the service
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            , 10000, 10000); //

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flag, startId);
}
```

Also in MainService:

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
    int Radius=6371;//radius of earth in Km         
    double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
    double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
    double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
    double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    double a = 0;
    a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    double c = 0;
    c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult= Radius*c;
    double km=valueResult/1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec =  Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter=valueResult%1000;
    int  meterInDec= Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value",""+valueResult+"   KM  "+kmInDec+" Meter   "+meterInDec);

    return Radius * c;
 }
```

LogCat:

```
 02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at com.*******drive.***.MainActivity$GeocoderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:231)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at com.*******drive.***.MainActivity$GeocoderTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
02-18 13:49:29.538: E/AndroidRuntime(13037):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be if you are getting the current location (in method `setMyLocation()`) using `getLastKnownLocation`. Then, you are getting the LAST KNOWN LOCATION which may not be your current location. If that's the issue, first, you need to get your actual location (there are a lots of ways, for example using `onLocationChanged`) and then calculate the distance and display Toasts...

Also, post your logcat when the app crashes...